# Fonts is not on top of image in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML code:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <img src="images/coffeebackground1.jpg" alt="">

<div id="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

This is my CSS code:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 704px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index:100;
    position: relative;
}

#topnav {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:1000;
    position: relative;
    color: red;
}
```

What I did was I put an image as a background and I want to put the topnav div lying on top of the background image. However, it seems like my code is not working.

Comment: change `background-color: red;` of #topnav... Background and font color both are same, that's why its not appearing.

Comment: Alright. I have changed the background-color to green but nothing is appearing still.

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 2):

The text is not visible because both the background color and the foreground color are set to red, so the element just appears as a red block.

Additionally, the text doesn't appear above the image because it is positioned as `relative` which means it will be positioned relative to its natural position according to the layout. As you haven't specified an offset in the CSS, it actually just appears in its normal position, which is just below the image.

If you change the position to `absolute` then its position will be relative to `#container` instead which I think makes more sense in this case. You can then move it to be above the image by setting a position, like this:

```
#topnav {
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 20px;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: No problem! If you think this is the best answer, please mark it by clicking on the tick below the score so that I can get the reputation ☺

Answer (score 0):

Background and font color are same, that's why its not appearing

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 704px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
}
#container img{
  top:20px;
  position: relative;
  }
#topnav {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="">
    <div id="topnav">
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How should the code be edited so that the word 'Home' can be on top of the Google image?

Comment: @NicholasMa Updated... check it now

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove position `relative` from `#container` and set position `absolute` in `#topnav`.

or

2. Remove `img` tag from `#container` and set background image on `#container` in css like that:

`

```
background: url("images/coffeebackground1.jpg");

background-repeat: no-repeat; //if you don't want to repeat image  

background-size: auto; //try others parameters to fit your background
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    margin:auto;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 704px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    z-index:100;
    top:20px;
    position: relative;
}

#topnav {
    z-index:1000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}If you want to change position of 'Home' please change #topnav:{ left: 70px}. If you want to increase more please left: 80px.. and so on. If you want to decrease please less #topnav{ left:30px.. and so on.}
```

Comment: If you want to change position of  'Home' please change #topnav:{ left: 70px}. If you want to increase more please left: 80px.. and so on. If you want to decrease please less #topnav{ left:30px.. and so on.}

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add your comments to _the body_ of your answer. Answers without any explanation are not very useful, and comments may be deleted at any time for very little reason.